# Частина слова на позначення почуття ненависті до чогось/когось?

Tags: запозичені-слова, from-greek

Маю таке питання: чому слово почуття ненависті інколи звучить із частинкою "фобія" (ксенофобія, русофобія, гомофобія), хоча *фобія* — це зовсім інше:

> *ФО́БІЯ, ї, жін. Нав'язливий, непереборний страх при деяких психічних захворюваннях, іноді при перевтомі, після психічного зворушення.*
> — [Словник Української Мови](https://sum.in.ua/s/fobija)

Чи можна сказати, що українці вживають в хибному значенні новотвір "русофобія"?

Comment: Може бути цікавою темою, бо дотична, ба навіть стати основою для відповідї: [How did phobia ever come to mean hatred?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/252787/226239)

Comment: _-Філія_ (_-фільний_, _-фільність_) і _-фобія_ (_-фобний_, _-фобність_) не завжди означають любов і страх (відповідно) в прямому значенні. Може бути також переносне (із доволі широким ступенем узагальнення), наприклад: [гідрофільність](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гідрофільність) і [гідрофобність](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гідрофобність), [ліпофільність (олеофільність)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ліпофільність) і [олеофобність](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Олеофобне_покриття). Мене тут особисто більше турбує використання кореня _рус-_ (адже _руські, русини_ — це якраз насправді радше українці ніж росіяни).

Comment: Але слова усталюються в тих значеннях, у яких вони усталюються, навіть якщо ці значення нелогічні. Наприклад, _гомофобія_ мало б означати страх подібних собі (наприклад, коли чоловік боїться інших чоловіків або білявка боїться інших білявок). Бо _гомо-_ і _гетеро-_ означають «подібний» і «відмінний» (як-от: _(гомо/гетеро)генний, (гомо/гетеро)зигота, (гомо/гетеро)морфізм, (гомо/гетеро)сексуальний_ тощо). Те, що називають гомофобією, мало б називатися _гомосексуальностефобією_ (чи типу того). Але склалося як склалося. А яке нелогічне слово _бус_ (_автобус_, _тролейбус_) — просто важко уявити.

Answer (score 3):

## міз-, мізо-

від грецього μισέω `[miː.sé.ɔː]`, «ненавидіти»

> *Мізо- (Miso-)* - приставка, що означає ненависть по відношенню до кого-небудь або чого-небудь.

Наприклад:

- [Мізантро́пія](https://sum.in.ua/s/mizantropija) ([Wiki](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F)) (грец. μισανθρωπία) — ненависть, недовіра до людей;
- [Мізогіні́я](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F) (грец. μισογυνία) — ненависть, зневага, огида, упередженість щодо жінок;
- Мізопедія (misopaedia) — ненависть щодо до дітей.

---

Стосовно слова, яке відображає почуття зневаги, огиди щодо громадян країни-терориста, то слово *русофобія*, що має значення *«побоювання руськіх»* не виглядає адекватним, тому що дієслова *«боятися/лякатися»* і *«ненавидіти/зневажати/гидувати»* мають суттєво різні функціональні значення.
Це тим більше вірно, враховуючи, що *«-фобія»* в українській мові має дещо інше значення, ніж в грецькій мові, і означає не просто страх, а **нав'язливий, ірраціональний, панічний** страх, про що вказано у словниковій статті, посилання на яку вказане у запитанні.

Також зрозуміло, що усталеного **словникового терміна ще не існує**.
Натомість, у мережі можна знайти [численні](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ukraine_UA/comments/y79xuq) [спроби](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/rusofobiia) знайти це слово. Найбільш поширеними варіантами є ***мізоросія***, ***москвогида*** та ***росогида***.

Comment: Є ще непопулярна спроба [-мізія](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-misia#English). Тий самий ж корѣнь «міз», але морфолоґія гинша.